# How we can find local maxima and local minima of data array with some outliers in excel

Tags: excel, calculus

[Time series data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF0Pk.png)

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrPZt.png)

In this data set, the graph formation starts around 6 and ends around 176,

can we get min result against 6 and 176 and max around 91. The data contains outliers so rules have to be applied taking into consideration the width as well.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what is being asked.  It sounds like `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS` might do what you are looking for,  [MAXIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)

Comment: I need to choose that minimum value which has a positive slope in the next few cells. Also, in the beginning, and in the end period values are consistently low. I want to identify the time when the increase in value starts.  Please refer the chart.